# How to compile the examples from the documentation?

Tags: windows, command-line, rust

I am following the Rust docs hello world program section, and I have it made and saved. Now it asks me to compile it by using the command line. However, it doesn't say where to start the command line from, or how to enable `rustc` command. I am hoping someone actually can answer this question, as I did not find much on the topic.

Comment: You should edit your question to include what platform you are on. It is also helpful if you tell us what you have tried. Opening the command line is nothing special to Rust, and there are likely very good beginner resources for your platform.

Comment: See http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/installing-rust.html and http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/hello-world.html

Comment: I have read both articles already, but after installing rust,, it says that it assumes I already know how to work the command line.  Anyways, I am on Windows, and using 64-bit release. I use shift+rmb inside the folder where the .rs file is located, and click open "command window here". when i type "rustc --version" like the tutorial says to, it says that rustc is not an internal or external command. Also, I tried adding the rust folder and rust\bin folder to path, but got the same error. I could not find even the most beginner things about rust, so I could not find an answer elsewhere.

Comment: I don't believe the Rust installer for Windows adds `rustc` to the system PATH by default; it might be easiest to re-install and make sure you do an "advanced" or "custom" install (whatever comes up) and ensure that you tell it to add rust to the PATH.  That way, `rustc` should work (if not immediately, then after a reboot).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. For anyone who is wondering, if you are on Windows you just have to add the Rust bin file to the path. You can go to:
Control Panels > System and Security > System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables. Then, scroll down to Path, and click edit. Add the path to the Rust/bin folder. I actually did this one time before I asked this question, but it was removed for some reason. Adding it backed worked for me.